# Is there any way to control my computer by using browser

Tags: javascript, browser

I was wondering if there was a way for me to control my computer through the browser, for example if you wanted to open the calculator when you press any keys like ( Ctrl + any keys ).

Is there any way to achieve that?

Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there is if you use an back end which runs on your PC. PHP or Node for example both can run cmd commands. You can setup an API which receives commands via http requests, send from the front end in the Browser.

But be careful if you plan to be able to control your PC via the internet. An publicly exposed server with permission to run commands is always a risk and has to be secured properly.